# How to update Angular to 6 only

Tags: angular, migration

The step ng update will update Angular to 7 now. But I only want to update it to 6.1. My current version is 5.2. How should I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Angular version can be managed by having package.json with specific version and do npm install and it will install that version.

```
dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "6.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler":  "6.1.0",
    "@angular/core":  "6.1.0",
    "@angular/forms":  "6.1.0",
    "@angular/http":  "6.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser":  "6.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic":  "6.1.0",
    "@angular/router":  "6.1.0",
  }
```